# OO Design whose responsibility input/output?

Tags: oop

I have a datasource (in this case a data file (HDF5), but might as well be something else like a DB). I want to load the data and output plots and pdf's (and maybe more in the future). Now how would I implement all these dependencies?

I feel a "data" class should only focus on containing and working with the data and not the loading of the data or the creation of output (pdf, image or other). However, the class does know what the data looks like and how it can be best plotted for example.

How would one build such a system in OOP?

Comment: How about a class for every type of data and an interface? Something like 'Printable' which can contain any output types you want. This way, any data can have different implementation but they all can be printed

Comment: That would be the case if the data can be different. Something like: excel->print() or db->print(). However in this case i have only one data format but more ways for output or input. So I wonder wether I should have a data object which does the reading itself: data = Data.fromFile() or data = Data.fromDB() and the writing like so: data.plot() or data.to PDF(). Where it seems that getting the data and creating the output might be better of in an external class.

Comment: Ah I think I understand better the problem now. It depends a little bit on the architecture of the system. For example, in a 3-tier architecture you may have a class for reading and writing (in the data layer), but if you were making a standalone module it may be good to have it all in the same class. I have very little knowledge in software patterns, but I would say that either choice is good as long as it has a justification